# Does the view count on questions include views from the author of the question?

Tags: support

I am wondering if, for example, the view count on my post will increase when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

NO not this way.

If you delete all your browser cache with cookies, active logins etc. and then login again and check your question, you will get +1 visitor.
Your question ALWAYS starts with 1 visitor, which is you. But you wont increase your views by simply refreshing the page. Otherwise many people had already the gold badge for 10k views, because you can create a simple firefox makro which refreshes the page every ms or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not - this can be tested by refreshing your question's web page real quick and then checking the view count, which does not increase.

Comment: Oddly enough, whenever you create a new question, it always has 1 view O_o

Comment: Are you sure this asks the question you posed in the title? ("Does the view count on questions include views from the author of the question?") When someone *other* than the author of a question refreshes the page, does *that* incrememt the view count?

Comment: This method does not prove whether a question's view count increases when other people refresh the question's page, but it does prove that the question asker does not have an effect on the view count in this way. The former question is probably more useful.